# Reading a file via open().read() vs storing it in a variable

Tags: python

I've written this small app in Python that will generate paragraphs of dummy text, kind of like [this site](http://www.lipsum.com/), except it'll work offline. Right now you're supposed to provide a reasonably long text file (I'm currently using books from Project Gutenberg), which it will call open() and then read() on to get the initial string for the operation, but what's to stop me from just including the whole text file in the program, as a variable? i.e

```
lorem_ipsum = """
***full text of De finibus bonorum et malorum***
***no seriously***
***yeah...***
"""
```

Are there any disadvantages to doing this versus reading it in from a separate text file?

Comment: There is a fundamental rule that is widely considered to be a best practice, and that is "Always keep your code and your data separate".  Why? Readability counts! Especially with Python!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a few problems:

- Your program becomes really hard to read.
- You run the risk of """ appearing in the text and blowing everything up
- You break the whole concept of content existing in the format in which it belongs.  The book in question is a text file, it should live in a text file and if Python needs it, it should pull it from there.  Otherwise newcomers to the app have to look **everywhere** for **every** type of data.  not fun.